# Loop through one line while splitting in Python

Tags: python, split

I have a big line inside a file. I'm trying to pull out of that specific line some data.

For example, line 107 of the file:

```
<test>H</test><test>E</test><test>L</test><test>L</test><test>O</test>
```

How could I do to split it X times until the end of the line, so it returns

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

But without using a parser.

I've worked on splitting the file in lines, but I can only get it to loop once until it finds the first part to split. How can I make it continue splitting trough the line?

```
matches = open('file.html', 'r')

for line in matches:
    test = line.split("<test")
    with open ('test.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(test[0].split("\">")[-1] + "\n")

matches.close()
```

Comment: You appear to have HTML data; use a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup instead.

Comment: @martijn It is indeed HTML, but I'd love to know the general answer. For example, if instead of <test> it was a normal word.

Comment: You may want to read up on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for future questions; explain to us what higher-level problem you are trying to solve instead of the detailed solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I posted my own code to show what I have done so far. The higher problem is splitting a line multiple times.

Comment: `str.split` will split it multiple times. Your problem is that you just write the first result to the file though: `test[0]` — `test` is a list of all results.

Comment: @BrickTop: what is missing is details about the input file and what you are trying to extract from it, for example. Looks like you are trying to extract text in `<a href="...">....</a>` hyperlinks in a table.

Comment: @BrickTop The higher problem is that of using structured data, but not having a parser.

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry for the noobish wording, here's hoping my Voodoo doll isn't being pinched much by the SO guru's. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a HTML Parser, such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It will make the job much easier, and it's designed for something like this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> s = "<test>H</test><test>E</test><test>L</test><test>L</test><test>O</test>"
>>> soup = BS(s)
>>> for i in soup.find_all('test'):
...     print i.text
... 
H
E
L
L
O
```

Also, you're opening the file everytime you loop through a line in the `file.html` file. You should open the `with` statement outside of the for-loop. This may fix your issue, as currently you're re-writing over the same line (because you open the file at the first line, write over, then close the file, and repeat).

Comment: I've done it with BS before, but I wanted to know the raw solution without it, would there be a possible way? And thanks for the with tip!

Comment: @BrickTop The raw solution? What do you mean?

Comment: Something that would use Python's built in splitting function.

Comment: @BrickTop You shouldn't do that when parsing HTML. You'll just make a mess, and it's not worth it, even if it's for teaching purposes. To teach yourself is to explore the variety that Python has to offer, and BeautifulSoup is something you can look at.

Comment: So, if it weren't HTML, but just a normal long sentence, how would it be done? Like, if it were a sentence like _This is a sentence that I want to split._ And I wanted to split what is between every T and S (This; tence that I want to s), how could I do it?

Comment: @BrickTop Look into regular expressions: the `re` module (I'd link you but I'm on my phone sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regular expression also.Its a simple python solution

```
import re
def strip_html(text):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', text)
```